# How to set the public variable value from the wpf user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have one dll which contains the wpf user control.

I have one wpf window in another wpf project which contains the above user control in that.

I have two public properties in wpf user control.

**I want to set those properties from the wpf window in which wpf user control is added.**

I have tried to do it using dependency property as follows :

TestUserControl.xaml :-

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestDependencyProperty.TestUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="test property" x:Name="lblTestProperty"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

TestUserControl.xaml.cs :-

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestDependencyProperty
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TestUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestUserControl
    {
        public TestUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetLabelText();
        }

        private void SetLabelText()
        {
            lblTestProperty.Content = TestProperty;
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDependencyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TestProperty",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(TestUserControl));

        [Bindable(true)]
        public string TestProperty
        {
            get 
            {
                return (string)this.GetValue(TestDependencyProperty);
            }
            set 
            {
                this.SetValue(TestDependencyProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml :-

```
<Window x:Class="TestDependencyProperty.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDependencyProperty"
        >
    <Grid>
        <local:TestUserControl x:Name="ucTest" TestProperty="HelloWorld"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I am expecting a label with content "HelloWorld".

So can anybody tell me how to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Have you ever set a property in WPF before? How did you do it last time? Why do you think this case is different? Are you having any specific, concrete problem here?

Comment: Did you use Dependency Properties?

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Thanks for replying, I have not tried binding public variable from user control property before. If you have any code snippet regarding this issue, please forward it. Thank you.

Comment: @Kelly Barnard Hi kelly, i have tried the dependency property, but dependency property always return null, so is this issue of "dependency property returns null" have any solution?.. Thanks :-)

Comment: @pankaj can you show how you implemented your Dependency Propety

Answer (score 0):

**User Control XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestDependencyProperty.TestUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding TestProperty}" x:Name="lblTestProperty"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**User Control Code:**

```
    public partial class TestUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public TestUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestDependencyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TestProperty",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(TestUserControl));

        [Bindable(true)]
        public string TestProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this.GetValue(TestDependencyProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(TestDependencyProperty, value);
            }
        }
}
```

You do not need **SetLabelText();**

Window Hosting User Control

```
<local:TestUserControl TestProperty="Test Text" x:Name="MyNewUserControl" />
```

in code behind if needed:

```
MyNewUserControl.TestProperty="New Value";
```

Dependency Properties have change notification built in to them so once a property is bound to them it will automatically get updated when the property does.